# How to store value in array?

Tags: ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray

**lookupAllForSQL** is a database function.
The table name and identifier are dynamic.

```
for (int i=0; i<FavIdent.count; i++)
{
    NSString *strfavarry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT  Title FROM %@ WHERE identifire='%@'",[FavTablename objectAtIndex:i],[FavIdent objectAtIndex:i]];
    FavTitle = [FavData lookupAllForSQL:strfavarry];

}
```

FavTitle should retain only last row found, but I want all the indicated columns.

Comment: why - votes can you please exaplain?

Comment: add your lookupAllForSQL method .

Comment: what is the type of FavTitle variable?

Comment: the lookupAllForSQL is working on my app but only problem in this part only

Comment: FavTitle is NSMutable Array @Anuj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lookupAllForSQL` is returning an array, so the value you store in `FavTitle` (which should be `favTitle` - variables start with a lower case letter by convention) is being replaced each time, resulting in the last value being left after the loop exits.

You need to use an `NSMutableArray` and append the sub-array each time through the loop:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i<FavIdent.count; i++)
{
    NSString *strfavarry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT  Title FROM %@ WHERE identifire='%@'",[FavTablename objectAtIndex:i],[FavIdent objectAtIndex:i]];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:[FavData lookupAllForSQL:strfavarry]];
}
favTitle = [tempArray copy];   // Convert it back to an NSArray
```

You should also use prepared SQL statements rather than string interpolation to guard against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you are **assigning** the result array from **[FavData lookupAllForSQL:strfavarry]** to **FavTitle** in the **for loop**. So **FavTitle** must always have last result array in it when the for loop executed.

use below code

```
NSArray *result = [FavData lookupAllForSQL:strfavarry];
if(result){
[FavTitle addObject:[result objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```